# Ionic 2 - How can I disable a button if there's no internet + valid form

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, ionic2, observable

I'm trying to build a form here using Ionic 2 + Angular 2. This form is a Model Driven form type, and all validations are made using Validators. Plus, there are two Observable that check if there's internet connection.

I haven't found a way to keep the submit button disabled while there's no internet connection and the form isn't valid. How could I make these two things work together?

This is how the code looks like so far:

**survey.html**

```
 <ion-header class="main-header">
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Questionário</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="form-bg" novalidate>
    <div class="form-content">
      <h5>1. Perfil do Fazendeiro</h5>
      <div class="question">
        <p><strong>1.1</strong> Em que perfil você se qualifica?</p>
        <ion-list radio-group formControlName="isPropertyOwner">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label><small>Proprietário do terreno</small></ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="owner"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label><small>O terreno é arrendado</small></ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="lease"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label><small>Outro</small></ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="other"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </div>
    <br>
    <button ion-button type="submit" block [disabled]="enableBtn()">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

**survey.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-survey',
  templateUrl: 'survey.html'
})

export class Survey {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(public alerCtrl: AlertController, public navCtrl: NavController,public toastCtrl: ToastController, public navParams: NavParams, public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.form = formBuilder.group({
      "isPropertyOwner": ["", Validators.required]

    });

    /* Check if it's online/offline */
    var offline = Observable.fromEvent(document, "offline");
    var online = Observable.fromEvent(document, "online");
    var status;

    offline.subscribe(() => {
      status = false;
    });

    online.subscribe(() => {
        status = true;
    });
  }

  enableBtn() {
    if (this.form.valid && status) {
      return true
    }
    else return false;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("model-based form submitted");
    console.log(this.form);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need a [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) to see if you online/offline. Actually its in [ionic native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/network/).

```
import { Network } from 'ionic-native';

let disconnectSubscription = Network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
  this.status = false;
});

let connectSubscription = Network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
  this.status = true;
});
```

From your code is see that you are using **var status;** it means that property is private. So you should define status in class scope to be visible in template

Comment: Thanks a lot Volodymyr, this could make easier to check if there's network connection. But, is there a way to associate this event changer with the form validation itself? I just couldn't figure out a way to make it yet :(

Comment: @CaikeMotta you have issue that you status is visible only in constructor. Define it in class scope same way as you did with form

Comment: I fixed it defining it in class scope as you mentioned. Though I had to do something else to make my logic work as expected:
`<button ion-button type="submit" block [disabled]="!this.form.valid || hasConnection()">Send</button>`

Now it checks both form validation and connection, so I had to replace && by || instead. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it! :)